# Implementing common random numbers in a simulation

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random, simulation

I am building a small simulation in Python and I would like to use [Common Random Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction) to reduce variation.  I know that I must achieve synchronization for CRN to work:

> CRN requires synchronization of the random number streams, which ensures that in addition to using the same random numbers to simulate all configurations, a specific random number used for a specific purpose in one configuration is used for exactly the same purpose in all other configurations.

I was wondering if the way I wanted to implement it in my simulation was valid or if I should be using a different approach.

My simulation has three different classes (ClassA, ClassB, ClassC), and ClassA objects have random travel times, ClassB objects have random service times and random usage rates, and ClassC objects have random service times.  Of course there can be multiple instances of each class of object.

At the start of the simulation I specify a single random number seed (`replication_seed`) so that I can use a different seed for each simulation replication.

```
import numpy.random as npr
rep_rnd_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(replication_seed)
```

Then in the constructor for each Class, I use `rep_rnd_strm` to generate a seed that is used to initialize the random number stream for the instance of the class:

```
self.class_rnd_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(rep_rnd_strm.randint(10000000))
```

I then use `self.class_rnd_strm` to generate a seed for each random number stream needed for the class instance.  For example the constructor of ClassA has:

```
self.travel_time_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(self.class_rnd_strm.randint(10000000))
```

while the constructor of ClassB has:

```
self.service_time_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(self.class_rnd_strm.randint(10000000))
self.usage_rate_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(self.class_rnd_strm.randint(10000000))
```

Is what I am doing here a valid approach to getting synchronization to work, or should I be doing things differently?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is a valid approach to make it replicable, **but only if** you can **guarantee** that there is no randomness in the order in which the various instances of the various classes are instantiated. 
This is because if they are instantiated in a different order, then they will get a different seed for their random number generator.

Comment: I agree that it is necessary to ensure that classes are instantiated in the same order, and I should have mentioned that I am taking care of that elsewhere in the simulation.

Comment: You could even design a test to show that it is the same. Modify your program so that every time a random number is generated, it is put at the end of list with the name of the classe using it. So that at the end you have list of the form:
[(Class A,66), (Class B, 92), (Class B, 12), ... ] 
if you run the programme many times and the list is identical, you are ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are seeding with a (pseudo) random number, so you're not synchronizing your CRN.

Consider:

```
self.travel_time_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(seed=self.seed)
self.service_time_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(seed=self.seed)
self.usage_rate_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(seed=self.seed)
```

Where self.seed is an instance variable set per class, perhaps from keyword argument.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.seed = None
    if kwargs.get('seed'):
        self.seed = kwargs.get('seed')
```

Comment: The issue is that each class has several attributes that are random.  In class B the attributes that require randomness are the service time and the usage rate.  How do I ensure that each attribute that requires randomness has a unique random stream dedicated to it, but such that I can repeat the simulation replication by specifying a single integer (which corresponds to the simulation replication number)?

Comment: Try npr.seed(some_instance_val), that will ensure that the random sequence from npr.randint() will be the same for a given seed.  I'd have to look at RandomState to see how that is implemented, but the idea of seeding seems to fit the bill.

Comment: If you look at the code I posted you will see that I am using the `replication_seed` to initialize the first random stream.  I then use the output from this stream to initialize all other random streams.  My question is, is this a valid way to making synchronization work?

Comment: @derNincompoop , but then you seed the PRNG again `self.class_rnd_strm = npr.RandomState().seed(rep_rnd_strm.randint(10000000))` with a random value, no?  Or am I misunderstanding successive calls to RandomState.seed()?

Comment: I thought I was seeding the class random stream (`self.class_rnd_strm`) using the output from the replication random stream (`rep_rnd_strm`).  Are you saying that each call to `npr.RandomState().seed(r)` in effect RESETS a global seed that is used?

Answer (score 0):

One initial setting of the seed at the start of your simulation run is good for the reproducible random numbers allowing you to reproduce any given simulation run exactly by re-using its seed.

Do nothing in your classes other than use calls to random.[method of your choice] to get your initial random numbers. Don't touch the seed again in the simulation run.

As long as all your randomness uses the random package and you avoid resetting the seed during the run, this should give you the behaviour you need.

Comment: I don't see how this would work.  I am trying to explicitly work around the situation where calls to the random number stream are not in the same order on the the same of two different policies.